# Azure Web app menu disabled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For hosting one of our asp.net application, we created an Azure account which starts with a free trial. Then I created a web app from app services menu. After web app instance is deployed and ready, I clicked on the web app for changing the settings I get a window with all the menu options disabled.

[image: Azure Web app settings window]

Does the Azure Free trial subscription have any sort of restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A site in a free subscription is fully functional, so all this UI absolutely should be available. As you found, after creating a new site everything started working.

Now the question is what prevented this from not working in the first site. My take is that it was likely a glitch in the Azure Portal (yes, it still has a few bugs), and that a browser refresh would have solved it. If you run into this again and a Portal refresh doesn't solve it, we can investigate further.

Comment: Note that my previous answer had been deleted with no explanation (possibly by mistake?), so re-adding this new answer with different phrasing.

Comment: My apologies, may be I had deleted it by mistake.

Comment: No, it was some moderator. Sometimes they get a bit overzealous :)